# What is the difference between local and remote transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

In latest go-ethereum, miners firstly try to mine local txs and
then try to mine remote txs.

what are the exact differences between them?

Comment: I've got a feeling you're reading release notes or something. Please do add links to what you mean by "latest go-ethereum", to a specific version. This will help the Q/A remain relevant as time goes on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "Local transactions" are transactions whose sender is an address that is in the running instance of geth. For example in a mining pool they would be the payments to miners.
- "Remote transactions" everything else.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Transactions created with all private keys in "keystore" folder seems to be local transactions.